# get_terms of post->id

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I need a way to use get_terms and have it only grab the taxonomies of the current page. Example http://sitename.com/genre/hip_hop would only grab the taxonomies that also have the hip hop genre attached.

wp_get_object_terms almost works for me but wont loop the way get_terms does.

Here is what I have right now

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$cam_brands = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'sub_genre' );?>
<?php foreach( $cam_brands as $brand ) : ?>
<h3 class="genre-title"> <?php echo $brand->name; ?> </h3>

<?php $wpq = array( 'post_type' => 'track', 'taxonomy' => 'sub_genre', 'term' => $brand->slug, 'post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1, 'caller_get_posts'=> 1 );
$brand_posts = new WP_Query ($wpq);?>
<ul>
<?php foreach( $brand_posts->posts as $post ) : ?>
<li> <?php echo $post->post_title; ?> <a class="sc-player" href="<?php echo get('soundcloud_link'); ?>">track</a> </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're looking for is [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms), which you can specify a post ID and a taxonomy to retrieve the terms attached to it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might want to consider changing your outer `foreach` to a regular `for` statement. I have experienced issues with iteration counts while using a `foreach` inside a `foreach` (nested foreach statements). This might be affecting the output of your code. [PHP has documented this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on their website.